# Doxygen grouping

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I have a question about pages and groups in doxygen. I have a project, where I grouped classes etc. with the @defgroup and @ingroup cmds. So far this works fine.

Now I'd like to add special documentation to the project with markdown pages. These pages should appear in the dedicated module (group). I tried to create pages with the @page and @subpage cmds. That works fine, but the pages appear plain in the menu.

So I tried to add them to the groups with @ingroup. But that doesn't work as I guessed. Is it possible to add pages to modules (groups)?

The result should look like this:

```
Project
|-- Modules
| |-- "Module1"
| | |-- documentation page1 (from *.md file)
| | |-- class documentation
| |-- "Module2"
| | |-- documentation page2
| | |-- class documentation
```

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 9):

In described case we have two types of documentation for groups:

1. documentation from source files
2. documentation from markdown files

And we need create tree structure for this goups.

For example, we create 2 groups :

1. *Main Application* with documentation in source code
2. *Library* with documentation in file *library.md*

*Main Application* group source code (for C++) may look like this:

```
/** @defgroup app Main Application */

/** @addtogroup app
  * @brief Main application description.
  *
  * @{
  */

int main() { return 0; } //do nothing

/** @} */
```

MarkDown file *library.md* contain simple text:

```
Library File {#library}
============

Library Page Content from library.md.
```

Now to define structure we create *mainpage.md* file with content:

```
Pages {#mainpage}
============

Content:

- @subpage library

@defgroup Library
@addtogroup Library
@copydoc library
@{
@}
```

`@subpage` tag in mainpage.md used to hide all pages from tree to one root item (Pages).
`@defgroup` tag create new group for markdown documentation.
`@copydoc` tag copy content from library page to Library group.

On screenshot you can see result structure:

[image: Doxygen groups and pages]

Note, that *Module Group* name and *Page* name may be different in that case. You can also paste content from MarkDown files into source code documentation using `@copydoc` tag.

Reference: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using @{ and @} commands and it works like this -

```
/**  
 * @defgroup module_name Sample Module   
 * @{   
 *     @page page_name [Optional Page Heading]   
 *     here will be the texts for the page ...    
 * @}   
 */
```

If you have the module already defined some where, probably you need to use @addtogroup instead of @defgroup.

Hope this helps.