# Doxygen: Group subprojects

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup

I want to generate a global documentation which should contain the documentation of the subprojects, but i have trouble to group it by the subproject.
The project structure looks like this:

top project a

- pages

  - *.md
- subproject

  - project b

    - doc
    - pages

      - *.md
    - src
  - subproject c

    - doc
    - pages

      - *.md
    - src

If i just let the documentation generate with the standard setup, all of the markdown files are on the same level. Therefore i want to group the documentation by the subproject. I know that if you add `\addtogroup [b,c]` to all files you can achieve that, but i don't want to adjust all files. In the best case, i would like the write one file in the top project which groups the input files like this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30148019/12042024):

```
@defgroup b
@addtogroup b
@copydoc doc_x
@{
@}

@defgroup c
@addtogroup c
@copydoc doc_x
@{
@}
```

The problem is, that you can only specify one file and not a directory, if i'm correct. I would have to generate an extra label for the subproject directory to copy all files. I also tried `\include` and `\ref`, but i couldn't really make it work.

The other idea i had, was to generate a "meta" documentation for each subproject, which i can then adjust with the `\addtogroup` parameter. I tried it with including the refman.tex of one subproject, but i didn't really looks like it works in that way. But in the end i just need a pdf, so can switch to whatever works.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Did you have a look at the tag possibilities (`GENERATE_TAGFILE` and `TAGFILES`)?

Comment: I'm using version 1.8.18.

I did not find any useful reference command to the tagfile. ```copydoc``` and ```ref``` don't work with the tagfile and with ```include```, it just copies the xml data into the pdf