# What is @ in C++ and why it is used in C++ header files?

Tags: c++, operators, comments, header-files

I was looking into the `queue` header file of `C++` and found a piece of code.

**PIECE OF CODE FROM QUEUE HEADER FILE**

```
#include <debug/debug.h>
#include <bits/move.h>
#include <bits/predefined_ops.h>

namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

  /**
   * @defgroup heap_algorithms Heap
   * @ingroup sorting_algorithms
   */

  template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Distance,
       typename _Compare>
    _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
    _Distance
    __is_heap_until(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _Distance __n,
            _Compare& __comp)
    {
      _Distance __parent = 0;
      for (_Distance __child = 1; __child < __n; ++__child)
    {
      if (__comp(__first + __parent, __first + __child))
        return __child;
      if ((__child & 1) == 0)
        ++__parent;
    }
      return __n;
    }
```

What is `@` and why it is used in multi-line comments. Also the text after `@` is highlighted in my IDE (in `@defgroup`), what does that mean?

I searched the web for the same but no satisfying result is found, the result shows `operators in C++` kind of stuff.

Comment: `@` is in the comments and not part of c++.

Comment: That's probably a Doxygen comment.

Comment: [Doxygen grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202909/doxygen-grouping)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@` is not part of the C++ language. Any characters can be used in comments. Comments can have markups that can be processed by 3rd party processors. In this case, `@` is most likely for [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/). Here is an example of the markups in the comments above: [Heap [Sorting]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/libstdc++/api/a01203.html).

Another example of markup in comments is [XML Documentation in Visual C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/xml-documentation-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160).